# Will my small twitter iOS app be affected by Twitter's user limit?

Tags: twitter, twrequest

I'm using the Twitter/Social frameworks to build a small Twitter app. It's not really a client, but you can send tweets from it and do a handful of other things (like view followers).

My question is, am I subject to the 100,000 token user limit? I am using TWRequest to handle everything from posting tweets to pulling in followers/lists etc.

From what I can tell, the 100,000 user limit does not apply to this scenario (as I haven't needed to generate a token to access any of that functionality) and I'm not replicating twitters core functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any application that accesses the home timeline or direct message APIs consumers user tokens.  However, your application seems to be for your own personal use.  Therefore, you're not going to ever need 100,000 user tokens.

Comment: It will be an app released on the app store (so not technically a personal app), however it won't access the timeline or direct messages so that answers my question. Thank you.